# Div content overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

I tried to set position of **v-container** (a div element) to be absolute and scroll attribute to be scroll in hope that the content would not expand and display over other areas of the site but it did not work. **v-container** typically contains about 20 **pilot-item**. Any solutions?

[Demo](https://ibb.co/YBpJVX3)

My attempt at it:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  container = document.getElementById("v-container");
  fetch("/report")
    .then((report) => report.json())
    .then((violates) => {
      container.innerHTML = "";
      violates.sort((a, b) => a.timestamp < b.timestamp);
      for (let i = 0; i < violates.length; ++i) {
        //if time stamp is not over 10 minutes yet
        if (Date.now() - violates[i].timestamp < 599000) {
          const infodiv = document.createElement("div");
          infodiv.className = "pilot-item";
          infodiv.innerHTML = `<div>Name: ${
                  violates[i].firstname + " " + violates[i].lastname
                }
                                <br/>Phone Number: ${
                                  violates[i].phone
                                }<br/>Email: ${violates[i].email}<br/>Time: ${msToMinutesAndSeconds(Date.now() - violates[i].timestamp)}</div>`;
          container.appendChild(infodiv);
        } else {
          console.log(violates[i]._id)
          fetch('/' + violates[i]._id, {
              method: 'DELETE',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }
            })
            .then(res => {
              if (res.status === 200) {
                infodiv.parentNode.removeChild(infodiv);
              } else {
                return Promise.reject(res.text());
              }
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
        }

      }
    });
}, 2000);

function msToMinutesAndSeconds(ms) {
  let jn = true;
  let str = "";
  const tmp = Math.round(ms / 1000);
  const minutes = Math.trunc(tmp / 60);
  const seconds = tmp - minutes * 60;
  if (minutes !== 0) {
    jn = false;
    minutes === 1 ? str += "1 minute" : str += `${minutes} minutes`;
  }

  if (seconds !== 0) {
    jn = false
    if (minutes !== 0) str += " and "
    seconds === 1 ? str += "1 second" : str += `${seconds} seconds`;
  }

  if (jn) return "Just now"
  else str += " ago"

  return str;
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: scroll;
}

#section-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  /* Center the element vertically */
  left: 50%;
  /* Center the element horizontally */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* Offset the element by half its width and height */
}


/* pilot divs container */

#v-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}


/* pilot divs */

.pilot-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5%;
  width: 22%;
  background-color: bisque;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: black solid 1.5px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 1em;
}


/* monitor area */

.map-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/* no drone zone circle */

#ndz {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!-- Create the canvas element -->
<div class="map-container">
  <div id="map" width="500" height="500">
    <div id="ndz"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<h2 id="section-header">
  <p>Violators for the last 10 minutes:</p>
</h2>
<div id="v-container"></div>
```

Comment: please add all of your code

Comment: Can you add the html/vue?